# When setting up uwsgi and nginx, do I have to create the socket file myself?

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

Am following up this tutorial to setup uwsgi + nginx to serve my django app

[uwsgi-docs](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html)

all going well despite it assuming that the user understand a few things about uwsgi!

Am in the section where am suppose to use sockets instead of ports for serving pages, this is the instruction

edit your **mysite_nginx.conf** ( I can do that) to;

```
server unix:///path/to/your/mysite/mysite.sock; # for a file socket
# server 127.0.0.1:8001; # for a web port socket (we'll use this first)
```

my question/confusion, What is **"mysite.sock"** is it a file i should create or what? What are the contents?

Paul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That socket file will be created automatically by uwsgi. If you look further in the [documentation you linked to](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html), you'll find instructions to put the following line in your `mysite_uwsgi.ini`:

```
socket          = /path/to/your/project/mysite.sock
```

This tells uwsgi where to create the socket for your application. The following line from your nginx configuration:

```
server unix:///path/to/your/mysite/mysite.sock; # for a file socket
```

tells nginx where to look for the socket. The two paths in each configuration file must be identical (or resolve to the same file).

As chuk2bp mentioned, the socket file is a communication channel. In this case it allows nginx to talk to uwsgi.

Answer (score 3):

.sock files are unix sockets (also called IPC sockets as well) and are programmatically created to allow information to be exchanged between processes.  In this case, mysite.sock allows for information to be exchanged between uwsgi and nginx. Sockets, when applicable, are used alternatively to ports which have much more overhead. For the purposes of similarity, think "piping" between processes.

[This article](http://www.techdeviancy.com/uds.html) in particular helped me understand sockets much more effectively. Give it a read!

Answer (score 0):

as *@Louis's answer*.

> server unix:///path/to/your/mysite/mysite.sock; # for a file socket

You just change

unix://**/path/to/your/mysite**/mysite.sock;

*to*

unix://**/home/h/workspace/sun-asterisk/POC-makeup/deploy-tutorial/nginx-tutorial/mysite**/mysite.sock;

*Note:* */home/h/workspace/sun-asterisk/POC-makeup/deploy-tutorial/nginx-tutorial/mysite* is my project path.